# Display only markers which are near user's current location in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I am using Leaflet js to detect current user location from the browser. I have bunch of markers being displayed in a given area. I would like to show only markers that are closest to the user's current location.

Comment: You can use `turf.inside` method of Turf.js library, see answer to this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151495/adding-markers-within-constituency-bounds-using-leafet-js-and-leaflet-pip?rq=1